# Model is not working in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created `MY_controller.php` and `MY_model.php`  in `application/core/` folder of setup .

When i extends the `MY_controller` class and create new class in `application/controller` folder it is showing me error

```
Unable to locate the model you have specified: My_model
```

### ***Same code is working on different server***

**Config.php**

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

**MY_controller.php**

```
/**
 * Base Controller with functions for CRUD operations
 */

    class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
    {
        /**
         * Constructor with common logic for pages
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('my_model');
        }
```

**MY_model.php**

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

**new class**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        /*
        * standerd requirements 
        */
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('site_model');

    }
```

Comment: what's your name of model  ?? Check the name of models and your class name for model .

Comment: This is CodeIgniter v1? My_Controller dont/cant load core model. It can load only from application/models/*

Comment: I would recommend auto loading the database library instead of this `$this->load->database();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > **First letter should be *caps* and all *other* should be *simple***

---

**Controller**

File Name - `My_controller.php`
Inside `class My_controller extends CI_Controller`

**Model**

File Name - `My_model.php`
Inside `class My_model extends CI_Model{`

Comment: @vipulsharma what is that server wamp or xampp?? is it??

Comment: it is not on my local machine it is live .

Comment: This is CI naming conversion. So all code should be restructure as well

Comment: I am already following that . please check my config.php file inline.  so but change i can do in MY_Controller to make it run . as i am calling Welcome Xends MY_Controller

Comment: The server in on linux right ?? Case sensitive restriction is on linux .So, check your file name and class name. The class name and file name must be in same case .

Comment: @vipulsharma sub class prefix is used to creating new library and new classes

Comment: ok can you please advise me what to do in my condition so that it works becoz error is only for model which is in application/core

Comment: Change all like i mention in my answer

Comment: @vipulsharma happy to help ;)

Comment: can you please visit this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824172/not-able-to-use-cake-bake-process-on-windows-cake-php-3

Answer (score 0):

Using the MY_controller and MY_model instead should be like below.

> application > core > MY_Model.php

**MY_Model.php**

And

```
<?php

class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

}
```

> application > core > MY_Controller.php

**MY_Controller.php**

And

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

}
```